# Floating point operations speed

Tags: performance, floating-point, benchmarking

Is floating point multiplication with 0.0 faster than average fp multiplication? The same question about adding 0.0 and multiplying with 1.0.

For the question to make exact sense: Is it faster on recent Intel CPUs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not on modern hardware. Modern hardware can perform all normal double precision multiplications/additions/subtractions in one or two cycles. Possible exceptions to this are denormalized numbers and special values like +/-zero, +/-infinity, and NANs. These exceptions take **longer** if there is a difference.

However, as with all performance related questions, truth is only in measurements. If this is important to you, measure it, then you know what to do.